# Retrieve a row which has maximum value for one column

Tags: sql, sql-server, where-clause

I have this query:

```
select * 
from COMMISSION  
where dealer_id in (select dealer_id from DEALER where COM_NAME like 'abcdef')
```

This query returns two rows which include column `STATUS_ID` with values 100, 102. I want to retrieve the row which has `STA_ID = 102`. How do I do that? Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
select top 1 id
from Commission
where dealer_id in (select dealer_id from DEALER where COM_NAME like 'abcdef')
order by Status_ID desc
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `max()` aggregation and correlated sub-query

```
select * from COMMISSION a 
where dealer_id in 
(select max(STATUS_ID) from DEALER b where a.dealer_id=b.dealer_id and 
       COM_NAME like '%abcdef%')
```

OR you can try below using `inner join` and `Max()` aggregation

As your status column is in commission table - you can try below query

```
select a.commisionid, max(STATUS_ID) 
from COMMISSION a
inner join DEALER b on a.dealer_id = b.dealer_id
where COM_NAME like '%abcdef%'
group by a.commisionid
```

Comment: I want row with maximum value of STA_ID which belongs to table COMMISSION

Comment: @Bommu, can you please provide you expected result and sample data in table format

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
select * from COMMISSION  
where dealer_id in (select dealer_id from DEALER where COM_NAME like 'abcdef') 
And STA_ID in(
select max(STA_ID) from COMMISSION  
where dealer_id in (select dealer_id from DEALER where COM_NAME like 'abcdef'))
```